# How to copy a string to other string ignoring cases?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, c++14

I want to change all the characters to lowercase in a string and copy it to another string.I tried the below approach in c++ but not working as expected. It is returning the string before a whitespace.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string s,t="";
    cin>>s;
    for(int i=0;i<s.size();i++){
        t+=tolower(s[i]);
    }
    cout<<t<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

For example if i give the input string "HELLO WORLD", giving result only "hello". Ignoring anything after space.

Is there any way to solve this in C++?

Comment: replace `cin >> s` with `getline(cin, s)` to read a whole line

Comment: Please also read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) and [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: `string s,t="";` you don't need the `=""` part. The constructor will initialize an empty string by default.

Comment: [this is what your code could be](https://wandbox.org/permlink/8tuerMhvSr3sGzCW)

Comment: See `std::transform`, especially, `std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), tolower);`

Comment: To copy strings, you can either use a copy constructor or the assignment operator.

Comment: @RyanHaining: Thanks for help

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Thanks. std::transform() is a nice one line approach